# jqGrid Tree Expansion not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jqgrid

Hello i am trying to build TreeGrid using jqGrid.Everything works fine but when i click on expansion on a particular node then the tree size is getting doubled.I can't understand why it is happening.

Following are the snapshots:

[image]

**AND AFTER CLICKING ON ANY NODE:**

[image]

Following is my JQuery code

```
function showMarkingUI(rfaID){
        $("#treegrid").jqGrid({ 
            url: '<%=request.getContextPath()%>/submissions/'+rfaID+'/jqGridJson', 
            datatype: 'json', 
            mtype: 'POST', 
            colNames: ["ID", "File/Folder", "Valid","Marked As","Level","Parent                   ID","HasLeaf"], 
            colModel: [{ 
                    name: 'id', 
                    index: 'id', 
                    width: 1, 
                    hidden: true, 
                    key: true
                }, { 
                    name: 'file', 
                    index: 'file', 
                    hidden: false, 
                    sortable: true 
                },{ 
                    name: 'valid', 
                    index: 'valid', 
                    hidden: false, 
                    sortable: true 
                }, { 
                    name: 'markedas', 
                    index: 'markedas', 
                    hidden: false, 
                    sortable: true 
                }, { 
                    name: 'level', 
                    index: 'level', 
                    hidden: true, 
                    sortable: true 
                }, { 
                    name: 'parentid', 
                    index: 'parentid', 
                    hidden: true, 
                    sortable: true 
                }, { 
                    name: 'hasleaf', 
                    index: 'hasleaf', 
                    hidden: true, 
                    sortable: true 
                }], 
            multiselect: true,
            treeGridModel: 'adjacency', 
            height: 'auto', 
            width: '500', 
            pager: "#ptreegrid", 
            treeGrid: true, 
            ExpandColumn: 'file',
            caption: "Record Folder" ,
            onSelectRow:function(id){                
                var ret = jQuery("#treegrid").jqGrid('getRowData',id);     
                if(ret.hasleaf=='false')        
                {                        
                    document.getElementsByName("group1")[0].disabled=true;
                    document.getElementsByName("group1")[1].disabled=true;
                }
                else
                {
                    document.getElementsByName("group1")[0].disabled=false;
                    document.getElementsByName("group1")[1].disabled=false;   
                }                         
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: where are the snapshots?

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this before. Normally, what it means is your data values for the parent, isLeaf, level, id and etc. are somehow messed up at somewhere. You need to check your data integrity.